# What are the 9 matrices used in the BFSS model of quantum mechanics?

Tags: matrix-model

The BFSS matrix model ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_theory_(physics))) "describes the behavior of nine large matrices"  using

$$ H = Tr(\frac{1}{2}\{\dot X^i \dot X^i - \frac{1}{2}[X^i,X^j] + \theta^T \gamma_i[X^i,\theta]\}) $$

Could anyone show an explicit construction for these 9 matrices as used in the BFSS matrix model, and show how these 9 matrices in effect produce a physical model please?

Comment: Perhaps they are the Gell-Mann matrices, for the generators of SU(3) plus the identity?

Comment: Wouldn’t an “explicit construction” require an exact solution? I don’t think one is known.

Comment: @flippiefanus No.

Comment: Also, I think the value of “large” that is of most interest in this theory is, unfortunately, ∞. The BFSS paper says “Our conjecture is thus that M-theory formulated in the infinite momentum frame is exactly equivalent to the N → ∞ limit of the supersymmetric quantum mechanics described by the Hamiltonian...”. (The matrices are N by N.)

Comment: @Ghoster thank you. This model seems related in some ways to SU(5) / SO(10) groups https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-commutative-diagram-showing-the-flat-space-BFSS-Matrix-theory-its-Z-2-orientifold-and_fig8_2056857 ... Have there been known explicit matrix constructions for SU(5) or SO(10)?

Comment: I’m not a string theorist and don’t know the answer. But when you say “explicit construction”, do you understand that these are *time-dependent* matrices (or at least I think they are)?

Comment: Where do you see SU(5) and SO(10) in that linked page?

Comment: @Ghoster Neither am i. It has been implicated in various sources though that the prominent GUT (electroweak+strong) candidates, SU(5) and SO(10), happen to coincide with the strings dimensions (10 or 11) in non-trivial ways, and the diagrams seem to point to some group justification for this model...